# Loop through MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I already googled looping through SQL tables, but none of the found solutions seemed to fit my problem. Here's the situation:

I got a single table. In this table there are approx. 7k rows and like 10 columns. Now I want to extract the content of 2 columns, lets call them source and target, for each and every row in the table. So in the end I want to have a new table 'result' with 2 columns 'source' and 'target' and approx. 7k rows.

How would I write a loop for that problem? Actually I just want to hit the SQL Request button and then wait for the results ;-)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what programming language are we talking about here? What 'SQL Request button'?

Comment: What do you mean with 'looping'? Do you need to select two columns from the table without any where clause? Isn't it a simple SELECT enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT source, target FROM yourtable;"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "{$row['source']} - {$row['target']}";
}
```